# Will switching on two-factor authentication stop my Heroku app accessing the Gmail server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, gmail

In the past, I've sent email from Heroku apps using the Gmail server, like this:

```
config.action_mailer.deconfig.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'derp'
  :user_name            => 'derp.bot',
  :password             => 'derp42069',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Since then I've enabled two-factor authentication for most of my domains. Before I do the same for my latest domain, will in wreck havoc with Rails code like you see above?

Comment: Wouldn't you just have to generate a password for this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the change does break your code, you could fix work around it by using an [application-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).